# python greenlet segmentation fault

Tags: python, ubuntu, concurrency, eventlet

I use ubuntu 11.10 with Python 2.7.2
I try to use eventlet or Concurrence, but simple examples fails with "segmentation fault"
I read this is a greenlet problem, but don't know how to fix this? plese help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try greenlet from https://bitbucket.org/snaury/greenlet

**Update:** The fixes from the above repo are included in the new 0.3.2 release of greenlet: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet